# Tweaking custom close reason for poorly framed code debugging/writing/improving questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons, code

In [Shortest code to reproduce GIS programming problems](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3994/shortest-code-to-reproduce-gis-programming-problems) I think we made good progress on getting a more useful set of custom close reasons for GIS SE.

However, I think the current wording of our newest custom close reason (borrowed from Stack Overflow):

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

is overlooking two closely related classes of question which I find problematic because they ask for code to be:

- supplied but show no evidence of having attempted to write any e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156564/how-to-export-coordinate-x-y-system-from-dwg
- reviewed and improved without having reduced it to a code snippet e.g. [Request for feedback on python script to increase efficiency with cursors](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157329/request-for-feedback-on-python-script-to-increase-efficiency-with-cursors) (I don't think we offer a GIS [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose that we tweak the wording above to become something slightly broader:

> Questions seeking help to debug/write/improve code must include the desired
>   behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code** necessary
>   to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Providing a **clear
>   problem statement** and evidence of a code attempt will help others
>   to help you. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
>   example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).