# Why was 6 year old question with accepted answer closed?

Tags: support, status-completed, close-reasons

I recently saw that one of my former questions was closed.

[Calling Python through BAT for Scheduled Task](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69766/calling-python-through-bat-for-scheduled-task)

While I can appreciate the need to clean up SO, I don't really understand the case for a close in this case. The reasoning is:

```
Closed. This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting answers.
When seeking help to debug/write/improve code always provide the desired behavior, a specific problem/error and the shortest code (as formatted text, not pictures) needed to reproduce it in the question body. Providing a clear problem statement and a code attempt helps others to help you.

Closed 3 days ago by PolyGeo♦︎.
```

This question (and answer) is about specifying the correct folder path and connection for an ArcGIS enterprise database through a bat file that calls to a python script. There is no code provided to debug since it is a path issue, further the problem and error is contained in the question.

I don't think this question should be closed, since there is already an upvoted (+8) and accepted answer. If the question was unclear and there was no accepted answer or upvotes I could see a reasoning for being closed.

I can appreciate that path issues are somewhat trivial but at the time of posting that question I was early on in my GIS career and the path/permissions issues of Esri were a lot to get through and troubleshoot on your own - which is why I posted here.

I have voted to re-open this question.

Answer (score 4):

In retrospect I made a mistake in voting to close this question of yours, for which I apologize.

As @inc42 pointed out in a comment on my earlier answer to this question, posting a [code snippet](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4312/115) is not a requirement.

I had forgotten about the outcome of [Replacing MCVE with Code Snippet in custom close reason?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4486/115) and the two lines of code that you had included appear to have met the minimum code required by the custom close reason that I used.

That custom close reason was added to the content curation tools of this site 4.5 years ago, as a result of [Shortest code to reproduce GIS programming problems](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3994/115), and so it was not available to consider 6 years ago, when your question was asked.  However, it is now, and your question was reviewed recently.

Our Q&A format is underpinned by wiki-style editing, and what your question encountered recently was the application of today's curation/editing standards in the same way that Wikipedia pages are subject to ongoing curation, and are expected to improve over time.

On your question, today's curation/editing standards were not applied correctly by me.