# Adding SQL (and other) Style guides to Tour?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tour

Would it be appropriate to add style guides to the tour, eg, [this very nice SQL style guide](https://www.sqlstyle.guide/)? I see a lot of [questions like this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282459/weights-assignment-based-on-intersection) where the formatting is so awful, I find it almost impossible to read, which makes me much less likely to attempt to answer it. The same could be said for Javascript, and even, Python, which despite the syntactical importance of whitespace, people still manage to make unreadable. I think it is unreasonable to expect question answers to have to reformat questions, and, at least if some guides were on the tour, it would be easier to kindly ask people to comply.

Comment: Are you looking for a similar function to stack-snippets? example https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0

Comment: Have any of the sites with more SQL Q&As than us discussed doing or implemented something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) has very limited real estate for us to modify - it is only the words above "*We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how:*" that can be changed.

Instead of trying to include reference to coding style guides there, I think the best place to do that is in the Meta GIS Q&A about [Writing code snippets to get quicker answers?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers)

As a result of your question I have added the additional words to my answer there about [writing code snippets for ArcPy questions](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4313/115):

> Sometimes a person's coding style can be off-putting to a potential
>   answerer who is deciding whether to volunteer their time to try and
>   understand a question before trying to answer it.
>
> One way to improve readability of Python/ArcPy code is to try and
>   conform to [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python
>   Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

I would like to encourage you, or anyone with the necessary SQL skills, to write an answer there about writing SQL expressions for quicker answers, and to include in that a reference to how conforming to the [SQL Style Guide](https://www.sqlstyle.guide/) can help.

Comment: Perfect, I will write something up on SQL when I get a minute. I doesn't matter that it isn't the tour, as long as there is somewhere to send people