# Sending archive through Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, status-completed

How can I send an archive through Stack Exchange?

My code is too long and is not accepted.

Answer (score 7):

You can't attach files directly to your Questions on Stack Exchange, however you could upload your file elsewhere and include a link to it in your Question.

That said, GIS Stack Exchange is not a Code Review site; Full, long, code text is not suitable for our format, and will often put off potential answerers who need to debug your code to find what is going on.  A very short *snippet* of code is required instead.  Questions about problems with code should include a snippet of the code that shows the problem and/or errors you are having with your code.

See also:

- [Writing code snippets to get quicker answers?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers)
- [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)