# Posting code and its link on GIS SE

Tags: support, code, formatting

How do I post my code and its link on GIS Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 4):

Posting just a link to your code in another repository will usually see quick votes for your question to be closed.

Instead, try always to be [Writing code snippets to get quicker answers](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4312/115) and then present your code snippets as formatted text by highlighting them and clicking the format button (**{}**).