# Why was question about PostGIS spatial functions closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Why was the question [Finding holes in proposed districts (Polygons/Multipolygons)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346888/finding-holes-in-proposed-districts-polygons-multipolygons) closed?

Answer (score 2):

It was closed as Off Topic because:

> When seeking help to debug/write/improve code always provide the desired behavior, a specific problem/error and the shortest code (as formatted text, not pictures) needed to reproduce it in the question body. Providing a clear problem statement and a code attempt helps others to help you.

If you feel it was closed wrongly, vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

That question starts:

> Thinking through something that I seek some SQL on:

so the question is seeking SQL code.

When I voted to close the question did not include anything like a [code snippet](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers) that illustrated what they had tried and where they were stuck.

We are a little different from other sites. We are a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that users show us where they are stuck with their own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in their question.  There is an edit button beneath their question which will enable them to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables them to format any highlighted code nicely.

We placed this requirement on coding questions here, and created a custom close reason for it, to prevent us becoming a code request service.  The discussions that led to that close reason include:

- [Guiding authors of code related questions to post actual code?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1965/guiding-authors-of-code-related-questions-to-post-actual-code)
- [Shortest code to reproduce GIS programming problems](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3994/shortest-code-to-reproduce-gis-programming-problems)
- [Tweaking custom close reason for poorly framed code debugging/writing/improving questions?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4006/tweaking-custom-close-reason-for-poorly-framed-code-debugging-writing-improving)

---

As soon as the user edited their question to provide more details the review queue introduced 7 new close/re-open voters to the question, and of those, 2 voted to still leave it closed, and 5 voted to re-open, and so it is now open.